# Mercurial repo search

Tags: search, mercurial

Is there a command that searches a specified string over a Mercurial repository and displays revisions where it is found?

If not, are there any examples of how to implement it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`hg grep <string>` will search your entire repository history for `string`.